# dynamically adding the value in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I am very new to javascript. I have a requirement to make a server call, get the json response and parse the response and populate the formatted response to a variable inside a object literal.

Its looks something like this below:

```
$('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "aaData":
        [
            [
                "",
                "1",
                "name-key",
                "description"
            ],
            [
                "",
                "2",
                "name",
                "description"
            ],
            [
                "",
                "23",
                "name",
                "description"
            ],
            [
                "",
                "24",
                "abs",
                "Common"
            ],
            [
                "",
                "5",
                "name1",
                "description"
            ],
            [
                "",
                "6",
                "name2",
                "description"
            ]
        ]
    });
```

In the above, I need to populate the aaData variable with json data from a server call. Please let me know how to get this done in javascript.

Comment: How are you communicating with server. Provide that code as well.

Comment: I am not yet come to that point yet. I came up with this solution:

person={
    firstname: (function(){
        return 'John';
    })(),
    lastname:"Doe",
    age:50,
    eyecolor:"blue"
}

Comment: Whats that? Your `aaData` doesn't contain any of these fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to call the server via AJAX. JQuery handles this for you quite easily.

Check out this link: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

A simple example of using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your url here'
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

You will want to make this call and set the data from the success function to a variable, format it correctly (possibly using for loops), and then use that variable as your 'aaData' value.